# New Trend In Typo Blod or Thin

Tags: fonts, typography, web-fonts, bold

Does anyone wanna share opinion on THIN fonts being used in mobile apps or even in websites? Is it the new trend.

In early stages of iOS7 beta releases Sir Jonny Ive's team used Helvetia 45 Light but not to be found anymore. Wht happened? Did accessibility centric designers cornered them?

Comment: Hi Rachuru. I think this question needs to be rephrased, as opinions are subjetive, and we try to avoid them for this reason. Can you maybe add some grounding, some examples, or more specific reasons why you think there is / isn't a trend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ive's team used Helvetia 45 Light but not to be found anymore. Wht happened?

They dropped the Light font replacing it with Regular in July 2013 - following lots of criticism from the design community that they were putting style before substance and sacrificing usability for fashion.

[**Here's a writeup of the change**](http://www.businessinsider.com/jony-ive-changes-his-mind-apple-makes-one-of-the-biggest-changes-ever-to-beta-iphone-software-2013-7).

It's impossible to know for sure if the criticism was the reason they dropped it, but it was one of the biggest serious criticisms of the early preview (alongside [taste-based criticisms of the rainbow gradients](http://jonyiveredesignsthings.tumblr.com/), and general surprise at Apple making an about-turn to follow a trend led by their competitors).